# Java: For and If

Tags: java

I am now a beginner to Java. I want to print out 1 to 10, then 9 to 1 using this java code:

```
package hello;

public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i = 1; i <= 10 ; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + i);
        }

        for(int i = 9; i >= 1; i--) {
        System.out.print(" " + i);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me by binding these things using 'if' statement?

Comment: **What** do you mean "binding these things using 'if' statement"?

Comment: Do they mean only using one for-loop?

Comment: The intention for programming exercises such as this is generally for you to think about the problem and figure it out for yourself.  You will learn much more that way than if someone gives you an answer.

Comment: If you use `Math.abs` you can do it in one statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ycf-l's previously deleted answer:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 19; i++) {
    if (i <= 10) {
        System.out.print(" " + i);
    } else {
        System.out.print(" " + (10 - (i - 10)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to print :

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
 ^_________________^  ^_______________^
    1 to 10              9 to 1
```

with one loop and if..else conditions you can use :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 19; i++) {           // The i should go to 19 because you want 19 digit
    if (i <= 10) {
        System.out.print(" " + i);        // if the i less than 11 print it
    } else {
        System.out.print(" " + (20 - i)); // else print (19 - i) + 1 until 19
    }
}
```